# How to evaluate 2D inverse Fourier transform?

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I try to solve the inverse Fourier transformation in two dimensional space of Gaussian function $e^{-tk^2}$

Started by the general form:

$\int \frac{d^2\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^2}  e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} e^{-tk^2}$

where $t$ is a constant, and $k = \||\mathbf{\vec{k}}\||$

Then, I turn it into polar coordinate to obtain

$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int \int e^{ikr\cos \theta} e^{-tk^2} k dk d\theta$

However, I'm not sure how to solve this analytically since the exponent contains $\cos\theta$

Comment: Instead of using polar coordinates, use $e^{-k^2} = e^{-k_1^2}\,e^{-k_2^2}$ and the Fubini theorem ;)